# How do you do this question on powersets and surjective functions?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

**Q:** Let $X$ and $Y$ be two sets and $\mathcal{P}(X)$ and $\mathcal{P}(Y)$ their respective powersets. Suppose that $f:X\to Y$ is surjective. Define $\mathcal{P}(X)\to \mathcal{P}(Y)$ by $f_p(A)=\{f(a)\mid a\in A\}$. Prove or explain why $f_p$ is necessarily surjective.

---

My thinking: I tried applying the surjectivity formula $$\forall B \in \mathcal{P}(Y) \exists A \in \mathcal{P}(X)[f_p(A)=B]$$. So consider $B\in\mathcal{P}(Y)$. We have that $f_p(A)=\{f(a_1),f(a_2),f(a_3),...,f(a_k)\}$ for $a_1,a_2,..,a_k \in A$.
But now I'm stuck and am not sure how to use the surjectivity of $f$ to complete the proof.

I also considered the alternative approach of trying to show that $range(f_p)=codomain(f_p)$ from starting $range(f)=codomain(f)$ but can't figure out how to relate them.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For each element $b$ of $B$, there is at least one element $x$ of $X$ such that $f(x)=b$, so pick one for each element of $B$ and make a subset of $X$.  Can you justify that $f_p$ of that subset is $B$?  In your thinking you never used the surjectivity of $f$.  You need to use it to prove the surjectivity of $f_p$

Comment: I'm still quite confused sorry. Is my interpretation of what you're trying to say correct?:

Consider $B\in\mathcal{P}(Y)$, where B is a subset of Y. Now invoking the definition of powersets and the surjectivity of f, for each $b\in B$, there exists some $x\in X$ s.t. $f(x)=b$, so we equivalently have some subset $A:=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_k\}$ in $\mathcal{P}(X)$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Thus, if we can show that $f_p(A) \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq f_p(A)$, we are done.

Comment: You are understanding correctly.  I think it is easier to argue from the construction that $f_p(A)=B$, but if you can show your last it is sufficient as well.

Comment: Why do we even need the double subseteq part?

Can't I argue by saying: 

$\{f(a) \mid x\in A\}=\{f(x_1,x_2,...,f(x_k)\}$. But since $\{b_1,b_2,...,b_k\}=B\subseteq Y$, each $b_i$ corresponds to some $f(x_i)$, so $f_p(A)=B$ by construction?

Comment: I don't think you do.  It is certainly one way of showing two sets are equal, but not the only way.